# Unable to connect TI SensorTag CC2650STK to IoT Foundation / Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

I can connect the SensorTag with the BLE SensorTag app on my Android phone and I can use the default Push to Cloud Quickstart setup to send data to IoT Foundation Quickstart. But I fail when trying to connect to IoT Foundation as a registered device.

I have registered the device on IoT foundation:

```
Organization ID         abcdef   (<- not my real org on IoT Foundation)
Device Type             sensortag
Device ID               sensortag1
Authentication Method   token
Authentication Token    somecrypticcharacters
```

In the BLE SensorTag app on my phone in Cloud Setup:

```
Cloud Service: IBM IoT Foundation
Username:      use-token-auth
Password:      somecrypticcharacters
Device id:     d:abcdef:sensortag:sensortag1
Broker add.:   abcdef.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com
Broker Port:   1883
Publish topic: iot-2/evt/sensors/fmt/json
```

When I enable Push to Cloud I get a

```
"Failed with error code: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the IoT Foundation connection ("Invalid userID () for device auth: ClientID....").

You can solve it like that:

- get the SensorTag code here :
  https://git.ti.com/sensortag-20-android
- Open "IBMIoTCloudProfile" class
- line 245, change the connection code 
  from

client.connect(options, new IMqttActionListener() {....

to

client.connect(options,this.context,  new IMqttActionListener() {...

- compile and install the updated app.